# Uniqueness of has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles

  def add_profile(profile)
    self.profiles << profile unless self.profiles.include?(profile)
  end
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates_uniqueness_of :linkedin_id, allow_nil: true
end
```

For some reason on production I get

`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Linkedin has already been taken`

on

`self.profiles << profile unless self.profiles.include?(profile)` line.

And after this I have duplicates in User.profiles records.

What is the problem?

Comment: Looks that a new profile is created. Could you add the context where the error is thrown?

Comment: Why are you using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship? Why would a profile belong to many users?

Comment: @max because particular profile can belong to several users.

Answer (score 0):

Using `has_and_belongs_to_many` is probably not the best option here.

If you have the quite common scenario where a user may attach several "profiles" or external OAuth credentials to their account you want a one to many relationship.

[image: Db diagram]

This example uses a generic `uid` column instead of `linkedin_id` so that you can use the exact same logic for Facebook, Twitter or any other sort of account.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
end


class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This guarantees that a profile can only belong to a single user. You may want to add some additional uniqueness constraints.

```
class AddUserProviderIndexToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index(:profiles, [:user_id, :provider], unique: true)
    add_index(:profiles, [:uid, :provider], unique: true)
  end
end
```

This enforces on the database level that a user can only have one profile with a given provider and that there may only be one profile with for a given `:provider, :uid` combination. Adding indexes in the database [safeguards against race conditions](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) and improves performance.

You will also want a application level validation to avoid the application crashing due to database driver errors!

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, scope: :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: :provider
end
```